# reboot causes device to shutdown but doesn't start again for many hours after

Tags: debian, cron, shutdown, beagleboneblack, journalctl

I am using a BeagleBone running Debian. I have a cron entry in /etc/crontab which tells the device to reboot at 03:01 every night as follows

```
00 03    * * *   root    /sbin/shutdown -r +1 >> /home/my.log 2>&1
```

This has worked perfectly for many months. The device shutdown and rebooted at 03:01 as expected.

However now, the device shuts down at 03:01, but the reboot doesn't happen until many hours later. In the case of today, it shut down at 03:01 but didn't actually reboot until 12:35:28, over 9.5 hours later.

With command *last reboot* , here is the response :

```
reboot   system boot  4.14.71-ti-r80   Sat Aug 17 12:35   still running
reboot   system boot  4.14.71-ti-r80   Fri Aug 16 08:58 - 03:01  (18:02)
reboot   system boot  4.14.71-ti-r80   Thu Aug 15 07:29 - 03:01  (19:31)
reboot   system boot  4.14.71-ti-r80   Wed Aug 14 04:41 - 03:01  (22:19)
reboot   system boot  4.14.71-ti-r80   Tue Aug 13 08:27 - 03:01  (18:33)
reboot   system boot  4.14.71-ti-r80   Mon Aug 12 09:37 - 03:01  (17:23)
```

When I check *journalctl -b* , here is the response :

```
Aug 17 12:35:28 beaglebone kernel: Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Aug 17 12:35:28 beaglebone kernel: Linux version 4.14.71-ti-r80 (root@b2- 
am57xx-beagle-x15-2gb) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.
Aug 17 12:35:28 beaglebone kernel: CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc082] revision 
2 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
Aug 17 12:35:28 beaglebone kernel: CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, 
VIPT aliasing instruction cache
Aug 17 12:35:28 beaglebone kernel: OF: fdt: Machine model: TI AM335x 
BeagleBone Black
```

What can be causing this issue? I am finding it very hard to diagnose. Thanks

Comment: This could be caused by a hanging service or some sort, could you attach a UART console and see what it said when it's trying to reboot?

Comment: @SandPox Thanks for your reply. I don't actually have physical access to the device. It is deployed somewhere connected to a cellular modem for communication, so I can only reverse SSH into it. When you say a hanging service, do you mean when it is shutting down?

Comment: Yes, when you try to reboot manually, does such thing happen? (reboot taking a long time)

Comment: @SandPox I'm afraid to try it now in case it will go dark again for another 9 hours or so :) I'm thinking to change the command in /etc/crontab to "00 03    * * *   root   sync && /sbin/reboot >> /home/my.log 2>&1 " Or is there a way I can forcefully stop all services

Comment: The `sync` command won't work because when you shutdown then it already does a `sync` and I don't think it's because of write cache takes 9hrs to flush. This may be caused by a misconfigured systemd service having an infinite stop timeout or some number that's really high (like 9.5hrs), have a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227017/how-to-change-systemd-service-timeout-value also if you desperately need to reboot, you could try `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` `echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger`, be careful with that because it won't sync anything, you'll lose unsaved data

Comment: @SandPox I've tried adding timeouts to some services. I manually did a reboot also now, and the device didn't come back alive until over 2 hours later. Could this be a hardware issue of some sort?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97533/discussion-between-engineer999-and-sandpox).

Comment: In my experience, systemd is terrible at rebooting or shutting down a system.  almost anything that goes wrong can cause it to wait and wait and wait and retry and retry and retry for anywhere from minutes to hours...or sometimes forever.    IMO a stupid design decision because sometimes the reason you want/need to reboot is that something (e.g. an NFS mount) has hung and can't be killed (so waiting for it to die before rebooting is cretinous).  yay systemd.

Comment: when nothing goes wrong, it works as expected and rebooting/shutting down is fast.  it's just terrible at dealing with problems.  and the last thing you need when trying to diagnose or fix a problem is for the shutdown process to take ages to get around to rebooting.  it couldn't be worse if they decided to go out of their way to maximise downtime.

Comment: @cas Is there a way to view the systemd logs to see if it is hanging and why? I'm checking all sorts of logs here, and there is just a "blackout" between the time the device should shut-down and when it boots again. Thanks

Comment: maybe.  depends on how much (and what) stuff there is to be done after journald is stopped.  try `journalctl -b -1` to get the logs from the previous boot session.  it should end with `$date $time $hostname systemd-journald[$pid] Journal stopped`.   that will at least tell you when journald stopped. and give you a history of what was stopped and when before that.  obviously nothing after that will or can be logged.

Comment: Now i'm looking at logs in /var/log/syslog when it is trying to shutdown, and I read this.. "beaglebone systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 5h 48min 22.614564s random time."

Comment: BTW, for this to be of any use, journald has to be configured for persistent storage of logs. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513212/journald-storage-persistent-just-disk-or-ram-disk

Comment: sorry, i have to go now - it's 3am here and i need to sleep.